# VBA - Worksheet.activate not working

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I was wondering if you could help me figure out why worksheet.activate does nothing in the case below. 
I turn off

```
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False,
```

-> create a new file and add sheets to it, 
-> turn them back on, 
-> and when i try to activate the new file, it does nothing, and the main file remains active.

Does anyone have a solution for something like this?

```
Enum getWhat
    getRow = 0
    getCol = 1
End Enum  

Sub main()
    SetProgramAlerts 0
    Set currentWorkbook= ActiveWorkbook
    Set newWorbook = Workbooks.add
    With newWorbook
        Set WS_Project = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        WS_Project.name = wsProject
        '....
    End with
    SetProgramAlerts 1
    newWorbook.Activate 'this actually does nothing, even though application.screenupdating = true
end sub

Public Sub setProgramAlerts(turnThem As turnThem)
    'TURN EVERITHING OFF AT THE BEGINING OF A MACRO
    'REMEMBER TO TURN BACK ON
    DoEvents
    Select Case turnThem
        Case 0      'All off
            With Application
                If .ScreenUpdating Or .EnableEvents Or .DisplayAlerts Then
                    .ScreenUpdating = False
                    .EnableEvents = False
                    .DisplayAlerts = False
                End If

                If Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
                    If .Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                End If
                '.statusBar = True
            End With

        Case 1      'All on in opposite order
            With Application
                '.statusBar = False
                If Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
                    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                End If

                If .DisplayAlerts = False Or .EnableEvents = False Or .ScreenUpdating = False Then
                    .DisplayAlerts = True
                    .EnableEvents = True
                    .ScreenUpdating = True
                End If
            End With        
    End Select
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not a 100% sure but i think the line `WS_Project.name = wsProject` should be `WS_Project.name = "wsProject" ` first. And i came across a similar problem last week, that a workbook wouldn't activate a sheet. The problem was that i had to refer to the `workbook` with the ending of it. For example: `Workbooks("yourwbname.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` However i know that you don't have to add an ending to the name of a reference, but it worked in a similar case for me.

Comment: In your procedure, what is supposed to be this argument: `Public Sub setProgramAlerts(turnThem As turnThem)`? Pretty sure that must return an error

Comment: Also, doing a procedure that passes an argument to a controller as a `Select` that has no specified default behaviour... that's one dangerous game you are playing.

Comment: the argument for setProgramAlerts is an Enum: 'code' Enum turnThem
    allOff = 0
    allOn = 1
End Enum 'code'

Comment: The code won't run - `WS_Project.Name = wsProject`.  You haven't give `wsProject` a value anywhere.  You also haven't added the Enum for `turnThem`.  Should the first line of `Main` read as `setProgramAlerts AllOn` otherwise what's the point of the enum?  You haven't added `Option Explicit` which is bad practice - misspelled variables are created as new variables, hides so many simple coding mistakes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After setting Application.ScreenUpdating = True before sheet.activate everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before:

> WorkSheet_Activate (and _Deactivate) not working

I have found a solution at least for my case.
A worksheet change, either programmatically or manually, activated a worksheet containing certain conditional formatting having UDFs (a very simple VBA function).
After deleting the UDFs and replacing them with Excel formulas, the problem totally ceased.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with not reacting worksheet events. I could finally solve it by simply closing and re-opening the workbook.